# Authentication failure with squared character in password

Tags: php, mysql, apache, authentication

I am using an Apache DBD authentication to log into a PHP application.
The password are stored in SQL using the PHP function password_hash() and using BCRYPT encryption.
Everything works well except when a user wants to include the squared character ² into his password: the authentication fails to perform.

Has anyone already met this problem before?

Comment: I just tested this and could not reproduce. I did `$pass = "abcd²";

$passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$verify = password_verify($pass, $passHash);
` and `$verify` came back as true. Do you have any code can that can reproduce what you are seeing?

Comment: I concur with @scott - it works for me as well.

Comment: Oops, Sorry, I wanted to comment and added an answer. Never experience this, but as a quick fix, you could just replace it for something else unique, since the password is going to be hashed anyway.

It's probably an encoding issue. Make sure everything is utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
Scott and Jay : the password_verify works for me too. It's really the Apache authentication that does not work with this character.
@peixotorms: interesting lead the encoding. The hashed password is stored in UTF-8. As for which encoding is used during the apache authentication process, I have no clue

Comment: Have a look at this: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31198